# Why is the encoding changing when I write to file?

Tags: r, encoding

I am attempting to make a boatload of Anki flashcards for Thai, so I did some web-scraping with R to extract transliterated elements from a website (dictionary). Everything looks good when printing in the console, but when I try to write the transliteration to a text file, the encoding changes, and I lose tone marks. Using `Encoding()` revealed that most entries were "UTF-8", which should be fine, but some entries were labeled as "unknown". You can download the HTML file from my [GitHub](https://github.com/trlemon/ThaimToLearn/blob/main/Thai%20to%20English%20dictionary%2C%20translation%20and%20transliteration.html), and my code is below for importing and extracting the text.

```
# Install appropriate library
install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)

# Read in page to local variable
page <- read_html("Thai to English dictionary, translation and transliteration.html")

# Filter for specific tags
translit <- page %>% html_nodes(".tlit-line") %>% html_text()

write(translit, file = 'translit.txt')
```

Comment: What OS are you using? Different operating systems use different encodings by default What is your system locale? How are you reading the file after you write the contents out to verify the encoding?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. RStudio is telling me the system default is ISO-8859-1. I'm using RStudio's Console to view everything before writing to file, but I am using Notepad to view the file after writing.

Comment: Windows default to using ISO-8859-1 (aka "latin1") encoding by default when writing to files and such. The encoding used for a given file is not generally stored in the file itself so you need to specify it when reading and writing if it's not latin1.

Comment: Still no dice. Specifying the encoding on read didn't have any effect. With the `write()` function I'm using above, there's no `encoding` parameter. If I try using "latin1" on import, the text isn't readable. It displays properly in the console when I read the HTML file as "UTF-8" or "UTF-16", but still isn't writing properly.

Comment: `write()` doesn't have an encoding option but you can set one on your connection. What about `write(translit, file("translit.txt", encoding="utf8")); readLines(file("translit.txt", encoding="utf8"))`

Comment: Neither of those options worked. I will still fiddle around with it, but I decided to use Python instead (worked like a charm!). Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringi)
stringi::stri_write_lines(translit, encoding = "UTF-8", "translit.txt")
```

[**stri_write_lines** (From `stringi` v1.5.3 by Marek Gagolewski)](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/versions/1.5.3/topics/stri_write_lines)

> Write Text Lines To A Text File.
>  Writes a text file is such a way
> that each element of a given character vector becomes a separate text
> line.
>
> Usage
>
> ```
> stri_write_lines(
>   str,
>   con,
>   encoding = "UTF-8",
>   sep = ifelse(.Platform$OS.type == "windows", "\r\n", "\n"),
>   fname = con
> )
> ```
>
> **Arguments**
>
> `str` - character vector with data to write
>
> `con` - name of the output file or a connection object (opened in the
> binary mode)
>
> `encoding` - output encoding, NULL or '' for the current default one
>
> `sep` - newline separator
>
> `fname` - deprecated alias of con
>
> **Details**
>
> It is a substitute for the R writeLines function, with the ability to
> easily re-encode the output.
>
> We suggest using the UTF-8 encoding for all text files: thus, it is
> the default one for the output.